# Dimension of the eigenspace at de Almeida-Thouless calculation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, spin-models, complex-systems

I'm now reading the paper [Stability of the Sherrington-Kirkpatrick solution](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/11/5/028/meta). In the appendix, the eigenvalue problem $G \mu = \lambda \mu$ is being solved. At (A.5), the following form of the eigenvector is suggested:
$$\begin{cases}
\epsilon^{(\alpha)} = a & \text{for }\alpha = \theta\\
\epsilon^{(\alpha)} = b & \text{for }\alpha \neq \theta\\
\eta^{(\alpha\beta)} = c & \text{for }\alpha = \theta \text{ or }\beta = \theta\\
\eta^{(\alpha\beta)} = d & \text{for }\alpha \neq \theta \text{ and }\beta \neq \theta
\end{cases}$$
And right below it, the paper says that these vectors span $2n$-dimensional invariant subspace.
I don't understand why these vectors span $2n$-dimensional subspace. There are only $n$ variants of vectors for different $\theta$, so I think these vectors span the subspace of dimension equal or less then $n$.